# printing such array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How could I print this array `var_dump($files);` produces this

```
  array
'Arrow' => 
array
  'Custom' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
  'Standard' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
'Borders' => 
 array
  'Corners' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
  'Embellished Outline' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
  'Simple Outline' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
  'Solid' => 
    array
      'original' => 
        array
          ...
      'thumbs' => 
        array
          ...
  0 => string 'cannon.gif' (length=10)
```

i want output like Arrow/Custom/thumbs/053_17_HandLeft.gif

Comment: I downvoted since you haven't specific how you want or expect the output. What do you expect to see, what are you actually seeing.

Comment: I think you should specify your question. How should your output look? Have tried `print_r`?

Comment: @Layke actually these are file paths so first border folder it has 4 folders corners and like these are files and their paths.

Comment: Could you be specific with the kind of output you need? There's already `var_dump` and `print_r` already, so by any chance are you hoping to output your array as meaningful html?

Comment: Presumably you are creating this list of file paths by reading some directory, and want to reproduce the paths of those files... How are you parsing those directory contents? Perhaps there is an easier approach.

Comment: @cbuckley yes i was reading directory i have solved problem thanks thanks again

Comment: @hira Could you provide the solution you went with? It's fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/), it replaces var_dump to show up like that, including syntax coloring and indentation.

Comment: Ahh, right, I though it was familiar. Indeed, it's XDebug's fault. Read [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/display).

Answer (score 1):

For beautiful lightweight debug, [Kint](http://code.google.com/p/kint/) does the job. Xdebug is great, but seems a little overkill to install, if only for pretty print or var_dump replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to output a list of file paths from some recursive directory structure. This function should help:

```
function createPaths(array $files, $prefix = '') {
    $paths = array();

    foreach ($files as $folder => $file) {
        if (is_array($file)) {
            $subPaths = createPaths($file, $prefix . $folder . '/');
            $paths = array_merge($paths, $subPaths);
        } else {
            $paths[] = $prefix . $file;
        }
    }

    return $paths;
}

$files = array(
    'Corners' => array(
        'original' => array(
            '1.jpg',
            '2.gif',
        ),
    ),
    'foo.jpg'
);

var_dump(createPaths($files));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($files);`. Maybe that will expand all arrays.